# How to read the current headers for an Ember Data DS.RESTAdapter?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I set up my `ApplicationAdapter` as such:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    headers: {
        'X-Api-Key': 'ABCDEF'
    }
});
```

Now I need to be able to read the current `headers` property of Ember's instance of `App.ApplicationAdapter`, so I can add to it:

```
var headers = {}; /* HOW DO I GET THE CURRENT HEADERS? */
headers['X-My-New-Header'] = 'someValue';
App.ApplicationAdapter.reopen({ headers: headers; });
```

How can I read the current `headers`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can change by object reference:

```
App.httpHeaders = {
  'X-Api-Key': 'ABCDEF'
}

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  headers: App.httpHeaders
});

// in some action etc
App.httpHeaders['X-Api-Key'] // "ABCDEF"
App.httpHeaders['foo'] = "Bar"
// etc
```

Or the ugly way: Taking the adapter instance via container.

```
var headers = App.__container__.lookup('adapter:application').headers
headers['X-Api-Key'] // "ABCDEF"
headers['foo'] = "Bar"
// etc
```

Comment: I would highly recommend setting your headers when you extend from the RESTAdapter.