# Ember: Get current adapter from model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm inside of a `DS.Model`-extending class and want to get the current adapter instance. I found some code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818181/how-to-read-the-current-headers-for-an-ember-data-ds-restadapter):

```
App.__container__.lookup('adapter:application')
```

But it looks quite hacky and I'm wondering whether there's a more correct way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This would be a bit better, since you're getting the exact adapter for the model (whether that's ThisModelAdapter, ApplicationAdapter, etc.)

`this.store.adapterFor(this.constructor.typeKey)`

Answer (score 5):

It appears that the APIs have changed since sheldonnbbaker answered. But in Ember 2.1 the following will do the same thing:

```
this.store.adapterFor(this.constructor.modelName)
```